# ReactiveUI - How to use SourceCache with ReactiveRecyclerViewAdapter (DynamicData)

Tags: dynamic-data, reactiveui

I am trying to use the `ReactiveRecyclerViewAdapter`. For the most part I have been reading up on DynamicData and following the sample at : https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/tree/master/Xamarin.Native/ReactiveRecyclerView

In order to use the `ReactiveRecyclerViewAdapter`, the base class requires a backingList of type `IObservable<IChangeSet<ItemViewModel>>`. In the sample you can get this from a `SourceList<ItemModel>` using:

```
items
  .Connect()
  .Transform(model => new ItemViewModel(model))
  .Publish();
```

But what if I am using a `SourceCache<ItemModel, Guid>` because my list items have a unique identifier which is used remove items. How would I connect this to work with the `ReactiveRecyclerViewAdapter`? I can get the following Observables from a SourceCache, but neither is accepted by the `ReactiveRecyclerViewAdapter`:

```
public IObservable<IChangeSet<ItemViewModel, Guid>> ItemCollection { get; }
public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> ItemCollection2;
```

I am missing something and cannot find any documentation. My goal is to display Insert, Move, Remove, Change... etc. animations automatically as the items source cache is manipulated. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**
Seems like I could convert the `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>` to `IObservable<IChangeSet<ItemViewModel>>` using `AsObservableChangeSet()`. But the now the Observables are not getting any updates that occur on the `SourceCache` (items).

```
ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> readonlyCollection;
items.Connect()
    .Transform(model => new ItemViewModel(model))
    .Bind(out readonlyCollection)
    .Subscribe();

ItemsCollection = readonlyCollection.AsObservableChangeSet();
```

Comment: ToObservableChangeSet is probably what you want to use instead. AsObservableChangeSet() just gives a snapshot in the current time while ToObservableChangeSet will keep updating.

Comment: As  shortcut I prefer exposing a ReadOnlyObservableCollection property for ReactiveRecyclerViewAdapter rather than the ChangeSet. It ends up doing the backingList.ToObservableChangeSet for you internally anyways, like Glenn referred to.

Comment: That was it! Going back to documentation must have misread ToObservableChangeSet as "AsObservableChangeSet" and didn't see the other method because I did not import DynamicData.Binding;  Thanks for the help!